# Starting new Activity causes app to crash

Tags: java, android-studio

I am attempting to start a new Intent inside `onPostExecute(`) method after an AsyncTask. The app always crashes however and there are no error logs. The `System.out.println()` calls return the expected output.

```
 @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.


            try {
                // Use the email address minus the '@' prefix as temp username.
                String[] uList = (mEmail.split("@"));
                String mUsername = uList[0];

                Serverrequest request = new Serverrequest();
                JSONObject userObj = request.getJSON(
                        "http://10.0.2.2:3700/api/login", mUsername, mPassword);
                if (userObj != null) {
                    // Account exists, return user
                    return userObj;

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Null response");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            JSONObject newUser = new JSONObject();
            try {
                newUser.put("username", "Charlie");

            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
            return newUser;
        }



@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject user) {
            try {
                mAuthTask = null;
                showProgress(false);
                System.out.println(user);
                String username = user.getString("username");
                System.out.println(username);

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("wordsmith", MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit().putString("username", username).apply();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StartScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("user", user.toString());
            LoginActivity.this.finish();
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Why are you using `System.out.println()` for logging? Android Logger or Logcat should have more information about the crash but i'm suspecting you forgot to add your new activity to the Android Manifest

Comment: Android Studio has been automatically adding my Activities to Manifest. I just checked, and it's in there. I'm using System.out.prinln because I'm not familiar with an alternative.

Comment: What does logcat say? Take a look at this article https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: 12-31 18:43:56.567 30786-30786/com.example.cameron.wordsmith W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.cameron.wordsmith-1/lib/x86
12-31 18:44:12.939 30786-30786/com.example.cameron.wordsmith I/System.out: {"_id":"5681d1625463d01354791aca","password":"$2a$10$TgoY3Zb8A6YsoKhUu0s8teEnWZZgoroLeCsZT1dx7KCa5NRWmAtii","username":"cameron","__v":0,"draw":0,"losses":0,"wins":0,"friends":[]}
12-31 18:44:12.939 30786-30786/com.example.john.app I/System.out: ron

Comment: Yeah the only thing logcat shows are my System.out.println()'s and that first line:  
12-31 18:43:56.567 30786-30786/com.example.cameron.wordsmith W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.cameron.wordsmith-1/lib/x86 12-31 18:44:12.939 30786-

Comment: Try calling this method somewhere in your code `Log.d(TAG, "Test");` to check that it outputs. Also are you running the application in debug mode as per https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#runDebug

Comment: I am running in debug, and the Log didn't show anything when I added it to my code and ran (and crashed)

Comment: Without a good logcat output i'm afraid I can't help you. Make sure you have your logcat filters off. At the very least you should be able to see that the logger log "Test".

Comment: I figured it out. The word 'System' was entered into the logcat reqex search and I guess it was filtering out all the logs

Comment: Feel free to post an answer, I'll mark it correct. Thanks for  the help

Comment: No problem, I don't think an answer would be needed for this :)